# Align numpy arrays based on array keys

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nlp, tuples

I was wondering how I could potentially align two numpy array based each array value's "key", for use in NLP (I realize that this could probably be done much easier with the NLTK, but I'm trying not to use it for this implementation).

For Example, say I have two arrays defined as:

```
array1 = [['dolor' 5] ['sit' 3] ['amet' 1]]
array2 = [['scripsit' 10] ['sit' 1] ['amet' 1]]
```

I would like the output arrays to be the following:

```
array1 = [['scripsit' 0] ['dolor' 5] ['sit' 3] ['amet' 1]]
array2 = [['scripsit' 10] ['dolor' 0] ['sit' 1] ['amet' 1]]
```

Would this be possible?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do here. It is also unclear if you need 'arrays' for this. It looks to me like a dict would be better.

Comment: @farenorth I'm using arrays because numpy arrays have several methods that would prove useful for NLP calculation (dot-product, magnitude, etc.). Is there any other structure I could be using that would provide such functionality?

Comment: It's simply strange to use arrays for string-value pairs like this. It can be done, e.g. with object arrays, but then you loose the functionality you mentioned. Perhaps you want a list of strings (or object array of strings), with corresponding vectors of values for each dataset?

Comment: @farenorth If so, how would I link them so that the array of values be aligned to a union of the two string arrays?

Comment: Is the order of elements in the final arrays important? I am not talking about relative order (that is order between array1 and array2) , but rather the order in a single list itself. Also, are the lists sorted initially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can get the unique keys then create a dict view of arrays and use a list comprehension to create the desire out put :

```
>>> all_keys=np.unique(np.array((array1,array2)).T[0])
>>> dict1=dict(array1)
>>> dict2=dict(array2)

>>> array1=np.array([[i,dict1.get(i,0)] for i in all_keys])
>>> array1
array([['amet', '1'],
       ['dolor', '5'],
       ['scripsit', '0'],
       ['sit', '3']], 
      dtype='|S8')
>>> array2=np.array([[i,dict2.get(i,0)] for i in all_keys])
>>> array2
array([['amet', '1'],
       ['dolor', '0'],
       ['scripsit', '10'],
       ['sit', '1']], 
      dtype='|S8')
```

*Note* :This approach will produce new arrays with same order.